# $-3\cdot7^x+2\cdot6^x+2\cdot5^x-2\cdot4^x+3^x>0$, for $-1\le x<0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Show that $-3\cdot7^x+2\cdot6^x+2\cdot5^x-2\cdot4^x+3^x>0$, for $-1\le x<0$.

Here its [plotting.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-3*7%5Ex%2B2*6%5Ex%2B2*5%5Ex-2*4%5Ex%2B3%5Ex%20from%20x%3D-1%20to%200)

By first derivative it involves natural log and expression become more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a^x$ is a decreasing convex function of $a>0$ for $x<0$. Hence
$$-3\cdot7^x+2\cdot 6^x+5^x>0$$
$$5^x-2\cdot 4^x+3^x>0$$
Add these up to get the needed inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't actually take the first derivative but simulate its ${d f(x)} / dx$ with $f(-\epsilon) - f(0))/\epsilon$ for $\epsilon$ between 0 and 1.